# how to solve changing view holder problem?

Tags: android, kotlin

when I click 13th item, then it start changing progressbar. But When I scroll up, then the 4th item also show that it is changed. I tried not setting recyclable false,but also got problem. when scroll up and down, the active holder is gone. I'm getting mad for this problem...  please help me...

*MainActivity*

```
   //ViewHolder Click Event
    override fun onClick(data: Any, holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder) {
        currentFragment?.initRecord()
        val holderPosition = holder.adapterPosition // and tried data.id
        audioPosition=holderPosition
        activeHolder = holder
   }

  //onChangeProgressBar
  override fun onChangeProgressBar(progress: Float, currentPosition: Int, totalDuration: Int) {
        if(activeHolder?.adapterPosition == audioPosition) {
            activeHolder?.let {
                showLog("activeHolder : "+activeHolder?.adapterPosition)
                it.binding.progressBar.max = totalDuration
                it.binding.progressBar.progress = currentPosition
                showAudioStopButton(it)
            }
        }else{
            showLog("Position activeHolder.adapterPosition: "+activeHolder?.adapterPosition)
            showLog("Position audioPosition : "+audioPosition)
        }
    }
```

*Adapter*

```
  override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int, payloads : List<Any>) {
        val data: ReplyData = mGroupDataList[position]
        if (holder is GroupPopupViewHolder) {
            //holder.setIsRecyclable(false)
            if (holder is GroupPopupViewHolder) {
                holder.bind(mGroupDataList[position])
                holder.binding.audioLayout.setOnClickListener {
                    (onClickListener as AudioItemClickListener).onClick(
                        mGroupDataList[position], holder
                    )
                }
            }


        }
    }
```

*Log*

```
D/TAG: Position activeHolder.adapterPosition: 22
    Position audioPosition : 13
```

Comment: please post the adapter class code

Comment: I added adapter class

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by adding listener when onBindViewHolder in adapter class.

*Adapter*

```
add listener in adapter class
 (onClickListener as ViewHolderOnBindListener).onViewHolderBinded(holder)
```

*activity*

```
//Do what u want
    override fun onViewHolderBinded(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder?) {
        if(holder!!.adapterPosition==audioPosition){

        }else{

        }
    }
```